# What form of schnell is used in “Und schnell und unbegreiflich schnelle / dreht sich umher der Erde Pracht”?

Tags: grammar, poetry

In the *Prolog im Himmel* from Goethe’s *Faust*, the archangel Gabriel chants

> Und schnell und unbegreiflich schnelle
>   Dreht sich umher der Erde Pracht;
>   Es wechselt Paradieses-Helle
>   Mit tiefer schauervoller Nacht;
>   Es schäumt das Meer in breiten Flüssen
>   Am tiefen Grund der Felsen auf,
>   Und Fels und Meer wird fortgerissen
>   In ewig schnellem Sphärenlauf.

[(Wikisource link)](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Faust_-_Der_Trag%C3%B6die_erster_Teil)

Now, I understand roughly what is being said, but the last word on the first line, *schnelle*, perplexes me. Presumably, it’s a form of the adjective or adverb *schnell*, but what grammatical function does the extra *-e* have in this context?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] for any questions about the site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s safe to say that the extra *e* has no *grammatical* purpose but is there only for rhyming and metric reasons.

The word *schnelle* is an adverb to *drehen* here, much like the first *schnell* in the line. The only difference is that the second *schnelle* has an additional describing adverb placed before it. Therefore, both words could be the same.

The meter of the verses, however, consists of a line of four trochees (with anacrusis) and a line of four iambs. The trocheeic lines and the iambic lines rhyme in pairs. For both to work, we cannot write *schnell* but need *schnelle*, adding an extraneous shwa to the end of the word.

Comment: A much younger example: _Dunkel war's, der Mond schien **helle**, schneebedeckt die grüne Flur, als ein Wagen **blitzesschnelle** langsam um die Ecke fuhr._

Comment: @chirlu Or *rasend **schnelle*** as I know it, but with the same argument.

Comment: According to DWB, _schnelle_ is the original form. Modern standard language dropped the *-e* (apocope).

Comment: well im a native and read the book at school. Its difficult even for me. Goethe uses a lot of metric speech. Sometimes he ignores grammar and sometimes he uses words wich did significally change in the later centuries